# How to set Wordpad's default plain-text font?

Tags: windows-7, registry, wordpad

I much prefer Wordpad to Notepad in Windows 7 for quickly checking out source files, namely because Notepad doesn't display most correctly if the file was written in Unix.

However it saddens me that I can't chose the plain-text mode's default font.

Is there a way to change it? I'm guessing registry here, if at all.

Answer (score 2):

Open a new document, set the default font and size, and save the file as 
"wordpad.wri". Close wordpad. Right click on the saved file and select 
Properties. On the general tab check read-only, apply your changes and 
click OK.

Whenever you want to launch wordpad, do so by double clicking the saved 
wordpad.wri.

[[src: Tom Porterfield](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/24573-45-wordpad-default-font-font-size) ]

Comment: Didn't think of that myself, thanks. I sure hope there's a way to set it for all opened documents as well.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I guess that doesn't really solve the problem of opening files huh? 

I'm a big fan of http://www.sublimetext.com/ on Windows. Probably more overhead than you want but it's definitely tweakable and relatively lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

You can change also the Icon of the shortcut, putting the icon of the Wordpad program, and to change also the name of the shortcut, so it will look as it's really the Workpad program.